# Filter table and display matching results - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The Goal**

I am trying to create a glossary where there are buttons A-Z along the top, and when you click one of these buttons, it will sort through a table, displaying only those that contain the letter as the first character.

How can I adjust the following so that it does this?

```
function filter_table(letter) {
    var rows = $('tr[data-filter]');
    console.log("Searching for keywords with ['" + letter + "'] " + "as the first character.");
    rows.hide();
    rows.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('filter').search(letter) >= 0
    }).show();
}
```

Comment: There is a great jQuery plugin [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) for working with tables.

Comment: Please post relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if the result of `search()` is `>= 0`, which will tell you if the character occurs *anywhere* in the string. `search()` returns the position where the search term was found in the string. You want to check if the position of the character is *exactly* 0, which means it is the first character of the string.

Though, it may be easier to just do this manually instead of delegating to another function.

```
rows.filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('filter')[0] == letter;
}).show();
```

Here's a demo:

```js
function filter_table(letter) {
    var rows = $('tr[data-filter]');
    console.log("Searching for keywords with ['" + letter + "'] " + "as the first character.");
    rows.hide();
    rows.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('filter')[0] == letter;
    }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-filter="apple">
    <td>
      Apple
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-filter="banana">
    <td>
      Banana
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-filter="canteloupe">
    <td>
      Canteloupe
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="filter_table('a')">
A
</button>
<button onClick="filter_table('b')">
B
</button>
<button onClick="filter_table('c')">
C
</button>
```